# Flex itemRenderer to bold dynamically based on the cell contents

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, flex4

Flex 4 Help I need an  itemRenderer to setStyle of the fontWeight of an entire row of a datagrid to bold dynamically based on the cell content of any cell in that row. So for example if the cell content  in my entire datagrid equals the string  ”ALL” I want that entire row that has that cell in the datagrid to be “bold”.  Note: this is not XML data.

```
Render

protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
            if (data.toString() == "ALL"){
                setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
            }else{
                setStyle("fontWeight","normal");
            }

        }

MXML Code
<mx:VBox width="100%" id="statsGridBox"   height="40%" >
<mx:DataGrid id="statsGrid" width="100%" height="100%" itemRenderer="com.jpmc.ctrbs.dashboard.alarms.renderers.FontWeightRowRender"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StephenNYC's answer worked however in the end I thought it was easier for the situation I was in to use an mx:AdvancedDataGrid and apply styleFunction="myStyleFunc" to change the fontWeight.

MXML

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="statsGrid" width="100%" height="100%" styleFunction="myStyleFunc" />
```

script

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
private function myStyleFunc(data:Object,col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object {
                if(data) {
                    for( var propertyName : * in data){
                        if (data[propertyName] == "ALL") { 
                            return {fontWeight:"bold"}; 
                        }
                    }
                }
                return {fontWeight:"normal"};      
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Comment: by accepting your own answer, despite it is an answer to a diff question from the original question, despite there are correct answers provided by others, despite acknowledging the solution given to you actually works, it doesnt encourage me / others to offer any help. chances are, youll be answering your questions a lot in the future.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, if you want the highlight to happen only at the cell level, put your code inside the itemrender "FontWeightRowRender".

In your renderer, you can do something like:

```
            override public function set data(value:Object):void {              
            super.data = value;

            if (String(value) == "ALL") {
                boldText.visible = true;
                normalText.visible = false;                 
            } else {
                boldText.visible = false;
                normalText.visible = true;
            }
        }
```

And

```
<s:Group>       
    <s:Label id="boldText" text="{label}" width="100%" fontWeight="bold"/>
    <s:Label id="normalText" text="{label}" width="100%" fontWeight="normal"/>
</s:Group>
```

Updated: example of highlighting a row

```
            override public function set data(value:Object):void {              
            super.data = value;
                            if (!value) return;             

            if (MyValueObject(value).isBoldRow()) {
                boldText.visible = true;
                normalText.visible = false;                 
            } else {
                boldText.visible = false;
                normalText.visible = true;
            }
        }
```

MyValueObject.as

```
     public function isBoldRow():Boolean {
          if ((this.attrib1 == "ALL") || (this.attrib7 === "ALL"))
           return true;
           return false; 
      }
```

Comment: I need the highlight to happen at the row level, based on the data content of any particular cell in that row. So ultimately I have a dataGrid that has 7 columns and the rows are populated dynamically based on how many times some alarms occur per date range. At the end of each day in the date range on the datagrid the alarm information has the string “ALL” in it and the remaining rows are totals for that day. I need this and any row that has this “ALL” string in that alarm field (which is actually MODEL_NAME coming for my database) to be bold.

Comment: so youre saying that if any cell in that row contains "ALL", the whole row should be displayed as bold? if that is the case, you can use the same itemrenderer code, and add a convenience function in your value object like "isBoldRow()" (boolean) and use that function in the IF condition in "set data()". isBoldRow would basically contain the code to decide if the row should be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Yyou should put your setStyle code in [overriden] set data method of your cell renderer. Then style gets set when the data changes, rather than when the renderer is redrawn (which may not happen when data is changed, as you are experiencing).

In renderer:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    if (data && data.toString()=="ALL")
        setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
    else
        setStyle("fontWeight","normal");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that the protected override function works. The issue is that it changes the entire fontWeight of my dataGrid bold. I just need it to change one row that has the cell with the “ALL” string in it bold, not the entire dataGrid.